# RoR Devise user creation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm currently setting up a new rails app. I try to use Devise for User AUthentication, but it's not working yet.

Im using rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.3 and devise 1.1.rc1

If i try to create a new user with app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb I get an **ActionController::UnknownAction** error

**backtrace**

```
Started POST "/users.user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-28 15:12:58 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as 
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4z6pC4ZivRA/YkEzUgPtOCrRGtMx0eGcrD5VU/kPJyg=", "user"=>{"username"=>"test", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up", "name_prefix"=>:user}
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::UnknownAction is deprecated! Use ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound instead. (called from service at /home/basti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::UnknownAction is deprecated! Use ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound instead. (called from service at /home/basti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::UnknownAction is deprecated! Use ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound instead. (called from service at /home/basti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138)
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms
```

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (AbstractController::ActionNotFound):
  devise (1.1.rc1) lib/devise/controllers/internal_helpers.rb:57:in `is_devise_resource?'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in`*run*_4273489613095160002__process_action_*4587107435389602145*_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in`process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in`dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in`call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in`each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in`call'
  warden (0.10.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (0.10.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`catch'
  warden (0.10.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in`call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in`context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in`call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`*run*_438428526525500157_*call*_3808880092983494302__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in`call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in`call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in`call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in`call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/basti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`service'
  /home/basti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/basti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in`block in start_thread'

Rendered /home/basti/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/unknown_action.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)

i've generated my devise with:

```
rails generate devise_install
rails generate devise_views
rake db_migrate
rake routes
```

my user model looks like:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me@config-initializers-devise.com"
  config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
end
```

**User looks like**

```
=> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, password_salt: string, reset_password_token: string, remember_token: string, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, username: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

any ideas?

Comment: `devise (2.1.2)` is available. update your devise gem and try once.

Comment: i see it is POSTing to `/users.user`. is that correct (user is your format)?

Comment: upgrading fixes it for now \o/

Comment: For documentation, refer [this](http://blog.blazingcloud.net/2011/01/08/devise-authentication-in-rails-3/) if needed.